# How to test several conditions with .endswith function in python

Tags: python, string, keyword-argument

I have a list of files with different extensions. Out of those I want to filter out only those with extension `.bam`, `.bai`, `.vcf` and some more. Is there a way to do it using the [endswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) function with multiple arguments instead of repeating it multiple times?

So instead of:

```
for name in list:
    if name.endswith('.bam') or name.endswith('.bai') or name.endswith('.bai'):
        # do stuff
```

Something like:

```
for name in list:
    if name.endswith(*['.bai', '.bam', '.vcf']):
        # do stuff
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`endswith` accepts a tuple of possible suffixes, as of Python 2.5. So it's just:

```
if name.endswith(('.bai','.bam','.vcf')):
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith