# How to search multiple values in endswith Python?

Tags: python, ends-with

Currently I'm making a bot with OpenAI GPT-3. I'm trying to see if the responses end with ".", "!", or "?" to stop generating responses.
Here's my code:

```
if a4.endswith(".", "!", "?"):
  if int(len(a + a2 + a3 + a4)) < 50:
    tc3 = a + a2 + a3 + a4
    print(tc3)
    raise sys.exit()
  else:
    tc3 = a + a2 + a3 + a4 + "."
    print(tc3)
    raise sys.exit()
```

This doesn't work and returns the error

> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

I'm wondering I could do without making more if statements because I want my code to look as least messy as possible so I can read the code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821022/how-to-test-several-conditions-with-endswith-function-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to use a single endswith.
If you have to use endswith, one way is to use multiple endswith:

```
if a4.endswith(".") or a4.endswith("!") or a4.endswith("?"):
```

However, I personally suggest using **index** and **in** instead:

```
if a4[-1] in ".!?":
```

which I think is more pythonic and readable.

What this does is first find the last character of string with index -1, then check if this character is in the matching string ".!?"

alternatively, you can put the matching strings in a list (or in fact any iterable).

```
if a4[-1] in [".", "!", "?"]:
```

Comment: Wow! That helped a ton. I did find out the first method but I will use the second method because of what you said. Thank you so much!